# Which ahadith relate to the last sermon of the Prophet and leaving behind the sunnah?

Tags: hadith, sunnah, source-identification

Just after delivering the last sermon, a companion asked a question from the Prophet (SAW) that if we could not understand from Al-Quran, "He SAW replied that you have my sunnah".

I am searching hadith about it. Because the Prophet (SAW) said that he left one thing Al-Quran in the last sermon.

Comment: In the [last sermon](http://www.islamreligion.com/articles/523/http://www.islamreligion.com/articles/523/) itself, prophet muhammad said: **I leave behind me two things, the Quran and my example, the Sunnah, and if you follow these you will never go astray.**

Comment: @Makz please post this as an answer.

Comment: And the question is? You want the actual hadith?

Comment: @user689 this info is too small to be posted as an answer.

Comment: @Makz the question is only about this,  you can some info and add it as an answer.

Comment: please there is two version of this hadith (even in sunni references) one say Quran and Ahl al Bayt and another say Quran and Sunnah: http://www.al-islam.org/shiah-are-real-ahlul-sunnah-muhammad-al-tijani-al-samawi/is-it-book-allah-and-my-progeny-or

Answer (score 2):

Salams,
This is the section from the 'Last Sermon' of Prophet(saw):

"O People, no prophet or apostle will come after me, and no new faith will be born.  Reason well, therefore, O people, and understand words which I convey to you.  **I leave behind me two things, the Quran and my example, the Sunnah, and if you follow these you will never go astray.**

All those who listen to me shall pass on my words to others and those to others again; and it may be that the last ones understand my words better than those who listen to me directly.  Be my witness, O God, that I have conveyed your message to your people."

Thus the beloved Prophet completed his Final Sermon, and upon it, near the summit of Arafat, the revelation came down:

*"…*This day have I perfected your religion for you, completed My Grace upon you, and have chosen Islam for you as your religion*…" (Quran 5:3)*

Comment: Can you give the reference of where you got the sermon from?

Comment: Sahih Al-Bukhari refer to the sermon and quote part of it. (See Al-Bukhari, Hadith 1623, 1626, 6361) Sahih Muslim also refers to this sermon in Hadith number 98. Imam al-Tirmidhi has mentioned this sermon in Hadith nos. 1628, 2046, 2085. Imam Ahmed bin Hanbal has given us the longest and perhaps the most complete version of this sermon in his Masnud, Hadith no. 19774.